# Sreadsheet Formula to generate a result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to make a formula which will generate a value in column F, Where Column D is random value inputed manually and the column G will use this formula (D/F)*100 to make the result 86.9744. It will be a good help as I am getting confused and ending up with wrong result.

[image]

Comment: I am also confused.  Can you edit your question to make it clear what you want?

Comment: Is this correct - " the column G will use this formula (D/G)*100" ?

Comment: You are right, Typing mistake, its (D/F)*100 for column G formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fill Column G with 86,9744.
2. Fill Column D with the numbers you want.
3. Formula for F column: **F1 = (D1*100/G1)**

Answer (score 1):

In G1 place your formula with the row number added to it and copy down.

```
=D1/F1*100
```

As you copy down or over the number or letters will change.  If you do not want a number or letter to change place a $ in front of it, or place your cursor on the address and press F4 until the $ are in the places you want